# how to send custom html verification email?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I want to replace the default verification email of Laravel 5.8 with my own HTML email, so, I tried to search in controllers to see where it is getting generated so I can replace but I could not find it.
My question exactly is: how can I replace the default verification email in Laravel 5.8? and how to access the same parameters that are in the default emai? for example the token and the username.

Answer (score 1):

You can override email templates. You need to run this first:

```sh
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-mail
```

Now in your `resources/views/vendor/mail`, you can customize the the email templates or create your own HTML templates there. The standard method is to customize or extend the default email templates come with Laravel.

But sometimes you may need to use an entirely new email template. In that case, simply place the new email template (inlined-version) in `resources/views/vendor/mail` directory and use that template using `view()` method in your mailables.